# ajax "callback is undefined" error

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I am currently trying to return a database call to fill a dropdown box. When I go to cycle through the list returned, however, I am getting a "callback is undefined" error. I've tried this code two ways, and neither is working.

I've tried:

```
$('#Vehicle_KovId_value').change(function () {
        var kovID = $(this).val();
        var drop2 = $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value');
        if (kovID != null && kovID != '') {
            drop2.get(0).options.length = 0;
            drop2.get(0).options[0] = new Option('Please Select One', '-1');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/Ajax/Index',
                async: false,
                data: { KovID: kovID },
                contentType: "application/object; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (record) {
                    drop2.get(0).options.length = 0;
                    drop2.get(0).options[0] = new Option("Please Select One", "-1");
                    $.each(function (index, item) {
                    drop2.get(0).options[drop2.get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.Display, item.Value);
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value').get(0).options.length = 0;
                    $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value').get(0).options[0] = new Option("Error!", "-1");
                    alert("Failed to load styles");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I've also tried:

```
$('#Vehicle_KovId_value').change(function () {
        var kovID = $(this).val();
        var drop2 = $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value');
        if (kovID != null && kovID != '') {
            drop2.get(0).options.length = 0;
            drop2.get(0).options[0] = new Option('Please Select One', '-1');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/Ajax/Index',
                async: false,
                data: { KovID: kovID },
                contentType: "application/object; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (record) {
                    drop2.get(0).options.length = 0;
                    drop2.get(0).options[0] = new Option("Please Select One", "-1");
                    fillBStyles(record);
                    //                    $.each(function (index, item) {
                    //                        drop2.get(0).options[drop2.get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.Display, item.Value);
                    //                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value').get(0).options.length = 0;
                    $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value').get(0).options[0] = new Option("Error!", "-1");
                    alert("Failed to load styles");
                }
            });
        }
    });

    function fillBStyles(r) {
        var drop2 = $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value');
        $.each(function (index, item) {
            drop2.get(0).options[drop2.get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.Display, item.Value);
        });

    }
```

Both of which give me the error:

> TypeError: callback is undefined

The data object being returned, `record`, is a list of database objects that I have to pull two pieces from.

How can I fix this "callback" error so that I can use my data in my function?

Comment: Where specifically are you getting this error?  If it's in the JavaScript console, what line does the error reference?  If it's coming from the server, then it's in server-side code and has nothing to do with this.

Comment: I'm using Firebug to debug the javascript part. It's telling me the error is at `jquery-1.7.js(line 654)` which reads `if ( callback.call( object[ name ], name, object[ name ] ) === false ) {` then breaks if that `if` is true.

Comment: Chances are you're using a jQuery function incorrectly, or passing it an undefined value as a callback function.  If you step through this in a debugger, how far does your code get before jQuery throws that error?

Comment: It breaks and throws the error at `$.each(function (index, item) {` from what Firebug is showing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A callback is the function to be executed immediately after its predecessor completes it's operation and returns a value.  In this case you have two callbacks, success and failure.

Function declarations are not allowed inside blocks (if/else/for closures) which means your callback function (which you declare inside your ajax closure) `function (record) { }` cannot be placed where it is since it is inside your `if (kovID != null && kovID != '') { }` closure.

Fortunately there is an easy fix: declare your success callback function outside the if statement (put it by itself in global scope) like this:

```
function ajaxSuccess(record) {
                drop2.get(0).options.length = 0;
                drop2.get(0).options[0] = new Option("Please Select One", "-1");
                $.each(function (index, item) {
                drop2.get(0).options[drop2.get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.Display, item.Value);
                });
            }
// ...do other javascript stuff
```

and call the success function like this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/Ajax/Index',
            async: false,
            data: { KovID: kovID },
            contentType: "application/object; charset=utf-8",
            success: ajaxSuccess
//...blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're using `$.each` properly.  Take a look at the examples in [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).  The way you're using it would work if used with a jQuery selector, but you're using the `.each()` that's on `$` directly.  Which means you're not supplying it with anything over which to iterate.  Take a look at your code:

```
$.each(function (index, item) {
    drop2.get(0).options[drop2.get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.Display, item.Value);
});
```

What is this iterating over?  For each *what* will this function execute?  You may have meant this:

```
$('someSelector').each(function (index, item) {
    drop2.get(0).options[drop2.get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.Display, item.Value);
});
```

or this:

```
$.each(someArray, function (index, item) {
    drop2.get(0).options[drop2.get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.Display, item.Value);
});
```

Either way, you need to provide `.each()` with a collection over which to iterate.  I imagine by the error that it's defaulting to the latter case, but since there's no second argument in your usage then there's no `callback` being provided to `$.each()`.

Comment: This, in combination with the answer from @Mike Hometchko, has helped to where the second drop down is populating. See my update for the current issue.

Comment: @Kendra: That looks like an error in server-side code.  It looks like you're calling `.ToString()` on a `List<T>`, which will generate that string you're seeing.  If you want the actual list itself, it needs to be serialized into JSON.  Without seeing the server-side code I can't really be more specific, but if you're returning from an MVC action then you can do something like `return Json(someList);` instead of `return Content(someList.ToString());`  I'm only guessing on what your current server-side code looks like, though.

Comment: That could very well be the problem. The server-side is currently returning a database list, which could be the same problem. I can post the code for that. No one here knows how to do this, hence why I'm on here asking. Normally, I can ask my coworkers how to work with certain code, but they haven't dealt with this before.

Comment: @Kendra: The comment thread is getting a little heavy here, which is generally frowned upon in Stack Overflow questions/answers.  I'd recommend separating these into two questions, as they're different enough issues that people can find them helpful in different enough circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Move your

```
function fillBStyles(r) {
        var drop2 = $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value');
        $.each(function (index, item) {
            drop2.get(0).options[drop2.get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.Display, item.Value);
        });

    }
```

above the other function.

and then use || vs &&
if (kovID != null && kovID != '')

Why do you need &&, kovID will not be equal to either one, but && means it must meet both requirements.

Comment: The && is in case someone sets the first drop down back to it's default setting, which has a value of `""`.

Comment: I just tried this, but that didn't fix it. Thank you for the suggestion, though!