# Ajax passed over data shows as null in C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I am trying to send some data in the form of JSON from my ajax post to a controller method in C#. Although I am not getting any data. I am verifying that data is there, hence before the second bit of ajax there is a console.log(data.model) to do just this. No matter what the model is always null on the C# side of things.

Javascript Post:

```
$.ajax({
    data: model,
    cache: false,
    type: 'post',
    traditional: true,
    url: mod.RespondentsTableUrl,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.model);
        if (data.success) {
            $('table.coldListTable').dataTable().fnRefreshTable(data.model);

            $('#numberOfResults').text(data.model.length);
            if (thereAreFiltersInPlace(model)) {
                $('#coldListFilterForm div.alert-container > div.nNote > p').text(String.format(Culture.Phrases.FiltersNoteFormat, data.model.length));
                $('#coldListFilterForm div.alert-container > div.nNote.dn').removeClass('dn');
            }
            else {
                $('#coldListFilterForm div.alert-container > div.nNote').addClass('dn');
            }

            console.log(JSON.stringify(data.model));
            $.ajax({
                data: JSON.stringify(data.model),
                cache: false,
                type: 'post',
                url: 'Respondents/DownloadCSV',
            });
        }
        else {
            errorDialog();
        }
    },
    error: errorDialog,
    complete: function () {
        //unhide cold list / filters, hide loader div.
        $('#loader').addClass('dn');
    }
});
```

Model:

```
public class RespondentCoreDataViewModel
    {
        public RespondentsData[] RepondentsCore { get; set; }
    }

    public class RespondentsData
    {
        public string Class { get; set; }
        public Data Data { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public object HtmlAttributes { get; set; }
        public bool IsLocked { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Source { get; set; }
        public object Email { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Ethnicity { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
        public string LastRecruiter { get; set; }
        public string OwningRecruiter { get; set; }
        public string RecruitingGroup { get; set; }
        public string LastActionDate { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string _class { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public long created { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller Method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DownloadCSV(RespondentCoreDataViewModel model )
        {
            ....random code in here
        }
```

Finally Json String incase anyone is interested:

```
[{"Class":"respondent clickable gradeA","Data":{"Name":"John Keys","Source":"<span style=\"display:none;\" >Database</span><i class=\"tipN icon-tasks\" original-title=\"Database\"></i>","Email":null,"City":"","State":"","Gender":"","Ethnicity":"","Age":"","LastRecruiter":"Ben Mabry","OwningRecruiter":"Ben Mabry","RecruitingGroup":"Board 2- Competitive Users","LastActionDate":"<span class=\"dn\">20131008175555</span>10/8 5:55 PM","Status":"<span style=\"display:none;\" >Completed</span><i class=\"tipN icon-check\" original-title=\"Completed\"></i>","class":"respondent clickable gradeA","url":"/Projects/644/Respondents/260619/Overview","Id":260619,"created":1386796133808},"Id":260619,"Url":"/Projects/644/Respondents/260619/Overview","HtmlAttributes":null,"IsLocked":false},{"Class":"respondent clickable gradeA","Data":{"Name":"Jim Walser","Source":"<span style=\"display:none;\" >Database</span><i class=\"tipN icon-tasks\" original-title=\"Database\"></i>","Email":null,"City":"","State":"","Gender":"","Ethnicity":"","Age":"","LastRecruiter":"Ben Mabry","OwningRecruiter":"Ben Mabry","RecruitingGroup":"Board 2- Competitive Users","LastActionDate":"<span class=\"dn\">20131008175529</span>10/8 5:55 PM","Status":"<span style=\"display:none;\" >Completed</span><i class=\"tipN icon-check\" original-title=\"Completed\"></i>","class":"respondent clickable gradeA","url":"/Projects/644/Respondents/260620/Overview","Id":260620,"created":1386796133808},"Id":260620,"Url":"/Projects/644/Respondents/260620/Overview","HtmlAttributes":null,"IsLocked":false},{"Class":"respondent clickable gradeA","Data":{"Name":"Jill Lellis","Source":"<span style=\"display:none;\" >Database</span><i class=\"tipN icon-tasks\" original-title=\"Database\"></i>","Email":null,"City":"","State":"","Gender":"","Ethnicity":"","Age":"","LastRecruiter":"Luanne Jones","OwningRecruiter":"Luanne Jones","RecruitingGroup":"Board 1-Mission Brand","LastActionDate":"<span class=\"dn\">20131009110258</span>10/9 11:02 AM","Status":"<span style=\"display:none;\" >Completed</span><i class=\"tipN icon-check\" original-title=\"Completed\"></i>","class":"respondent clickable gradeA","url":"/Projects/644/Respondents/260621/Overview","Id":260621,"created":1386796133808},"Id":260621,"Url":"/Projects/644/Respondents/260621/Overview","HtmlAttributes":null,"IsLocked":false},{"Class":"respondent clickable gradeA","Data":{"Name":"Charlie Neese","Source":"<span style=\"display:none;\" >Database</span><i class=\"tipN icon-tasks\" original-title=\"Database\"></i>","Email":null,"City":"","State":"","Gender":"","Ethnicity":"","Age":"","LastRecruiter":"Luanne Jones","OwningRecruiter":"Luanne Jones","RecruitingGroup":"Board 2- Competitive Users","LastActionDate":"<span class=\"dn\">20131009112301</span>10/9 11:23 AM","Status":"<span style=\"display:none;\" >Completed</span><i class=\"tipN icon-check\" original-title=\"Completed\"></i>","class":"respondent clickable gradeA","url":"/Projects/644/Respondents/260622/Overview","Id":260622,"created":1386796133808},"Id":260622,"Url":"/Projects/644/Respondents/260622/Overview","HtmlAttributes":null,"IsLocked":false},{"Class":"respondent clickable gradeA","Data":{"Name":"Tara Reid","Source":"<span style=\"display:none;\" >Database</span><i class=\"tipN icon-tasks\" original-title=\"Database\"></i>","Email":null,"City":"","State":"","Gender":"","Ethnicity":"","Age":"","LastRecruiter":"Luanne Jones","OwningRecruiter":"Luanne Jones","RecruitingGroup":"Board 2- Competitive Users","LastActionDate":"<span class=\"dn\">20131009112221</span>10/9 11:22 AM","Status":"<span style=\"display:none;\" >Completed</span><i class=\"tipN icon-check\" original-title=\"Completed\"></i>","class":"respondent clickable gradeA","url":"/Projects/644/Respondents/260623/Overview","Id":260623,"created":1386796133808},"Id":260623,"Url":"/Projects/644/Respondents/260623/Overview","HtmlAttributes":null,"IsLocked":false}]
```

Comment: In your ajax call add `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8` and `dataType: 'json'`. If everything else is right, this should fix the problem.

Comment: your call should look like 
`jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: successCallBack,
        error: errorCallBack,
 })`

Comment: @ShuhelAhmed I agree the `callBack` functions are set up incorrectly. I had a similar problem with ajax when I was first learning it a short time ago.

Comment: Oh, and as you are expecting a `RespondentCoreDataViewModel` your `JSON` should look like: `{"RepondentsCore" : [....]}`. Your array is fine. Just make a json object out of it.

Answer (score 2):

I actually had a [similar problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234006/ajax-callback-is-undefined-error)

The solution to mine was in the block:

```
success: function () {
//code here
}
```

You need to put the name of your success function here. Example:

```
success{
//code here
}

ajaxSuccess(result)
{
//code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you're close.  I think it's because your action method expects a named parameter called "model" you need to do this:

```
$.ajax({
data: {model: model},
...
```

I think if you add that it your ajax request will send the data in the format that will get auto mapped to your action method parameter.

BTW it will be better if you rename one of the parameters, data:{model:model} is not good practice IMO i would rename your js variable name for clarity something like:

```
$.ajax({
data: {model: jsModel},
```

Comment: I believe this has something to do with it as well. Although when i make the change I get a new error: [ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: model.]

Comment: i found my problem it was in my ajax. I posted the fix above

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Newtonsoft.Json to your project with PM console:

```
install-package Newtonsoft.Json
```

and rebuild your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the JSON being sent (model from `data: model` in the ajax call) is valid, I would do as Roman suggested...add Newtonsoft.Json to your project.

You should also use the JsonResult method when dealing with JSON rather than ActionResult:

```
public JsonResult DownloadCSV(RespondentCoreDataViewModel model )
{
   // blah blah
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I had to change my ajax script to look like so and it just worked! Oh and ignore the success and error those were for testing.

```
$.ajax({
                        data: JSON.stringify(data.model),
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'Respondents/DownloadCSV',
                        success: function () { alert('success'); },
                        error: function () { alert('unsuccessful'); },
                    });
```