# ajax sucess function, dont appears items

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Strange, I get 200 OK in firebug but return items are not displayed. Have tried using each and loop but without success. 
No error appears in the error function. 
Console.log messages and alerts are never displayed on the console.

```
$('#buscafrete').click(function(e) { 

    e.preventDefault();
    cep = $('#cep').val();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: "{% url 'get_frete' %}",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            data:cep,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}',
        },        
        sucess: function(retorno){
            $.each(retorno, function(i, item) {
            console.log(i);
            console.log(item);
            console.log("TEST");
            alert("TEST");
            });                
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            //alert("FALHOU");
            console.log('Error');
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },
    });

});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you're actually having a problem with it at the moment, but I did have a problem with a similar setup. You'll want your success and error functions seperate and just put their call in the `success:` and `error:` spots. For more information, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234006/ajax-callback-is-undefined-error

Comment: print some dummy data on requested url side, try it whether it is appearing, using firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo: `sucess` should be `success`.

Answer (score 0):

there is an error in your success function there is spell mistake function should be success instead of sucess 
it will not show any error but your code will not work.